# How can I dynamically assign multiple values returned from a response to variables in Apache jmeter? (number of elements in array may vary)

Tags: jmeter

I have a response data returned from the test, I need to take all of the "detailId"s here (their numbers may vary) and assign them to the variables. How can I do this in apache jmeter?

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form, _and in english language_ - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: i will heed your warning thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) configured like:

- Names of created variables: anything meaningful, i.e. `satisSiparisDetayId`
- JSON Path Expressions: `$..satisSiparisDetayId`
- Match No.: `-1`

[image]

This way you will get the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) created:

```
satisSiparisDetayId_1=7
satisSiparisDetayId_2=8
satisSiparisDetayId_3=9
satisSiparisDetayId_4=10
satisSiparisDetayId_matchNr=4
```

[image]

More information:

- [JsonPath - Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)